# Rails 5 Devise API Adding Confirmable Issues - missing required keys: [:format]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, registration

I'm trying to setup user registrations with confirmable via API calls. It creates the user just fine if I don't enable confirmable, but if I do, I get the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :confirmation_token=>"hidden", :controller=>"api/users/confirmations"}, missing required keys: [:format]
```

My guess is it needs something to specify JSON for confirmable, but I have no idea what to do.

I've already specified in the Confirmations Controller to accept JSON:

```
class Api::Users::ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  respond_to :json
end
```

And here is my registrations controller:

```
class Api::Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
  # before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  respond_to :json

  # POST /resource
  def create
    super
  end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:email, :password, :first_name, :last_name])
  end
end
```

Here are my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  scope :api, "/1", module: "api", :format => true do
    devise_for :users, :controllers => {registrations: 'api/users/registrations', passwords: "api/users/passwords", confirmations: "api/users/confirmations"}
    post 'auth_user' => 'authentication#authenticate_user'
    devise_scope :user do
        post 'password/forgot', to: 'users/passwords#forgot'
        post 'password/reset', to: 'users/passwords#reset'
    end
  end

end
```

And here is the API call I make, which is a POST to api/1/users.json

```
{
    "user": {
        "first_name": "Dev",
        "last_name": "Dude",
        "email": "dev@null.com",
        "password": "!1Qwerty"
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the behaviour of devise if you use confirmable? 
Are you expecting the API to just return the success response that the user has been created? @Erick

Comment: I expect it to return a 200 status of some sort, and send an email to the user.

Comment: Can you try to override `after_sign_in_path_for` method and redirect it to show user method?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I just had to force devise to always set the format to JSON in the routes, rather than just setting respond_to in the controller:

This is the line I changed in the routes. Note the added defaults param:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {registrations: 'api/users/registrations', passwords: "api/users/passwords", confirmations: "api/users/confirmations"}, :defaults => { :format => :json }
```